# how to ignore the "dots" in quotation marks

Tags: java, regex, string

i want to ignore the `.` in quotation marks. what the regex should i use?

example sentences :

```
String sentence = "i love you. \"i'm sorry. but love someone else,\" he said to me. ";
```

there are three `.` but i want to ignore the `.` in quotation marks in order to the sum of sentence is two.

my code and some regex that i have :

```
public static String[] ignoreWord(String word){
String [] arrWords = word.replaceAll(", *| , *|- *| - *|\\( *| \\( *|\\) *|\\{ *| \\} *| \\} *| \\{*|\\} *", " ").split("\\. ");
return arrWords;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\.(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/zX3tG3/1

Comment: can you explain more. i still learn. 
why when i split the sentence they don't like this : `i love you` and `"i'm sorry. but love someone else,\" he said to me` ?

Comment: @user3934214 it says that the `.` should have `""` pattern ahead of it.no isolated `"` should be there ahead of it.if there is an isolated `"` ahead that means the `.` is in between `"` and `"`.

Comment: so, in order to the the `.` in quotation marks is not splitted, what should i do? i just wanna split sentences by `.` except between `" "`

Comment: @user3934214 use regex.split and the regex i posted.